# Read multiple nodes based on Condition

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

I have the following XML structure. This is just an extract the file contains multiple nodes of 'PName' under 'PList'. I have just shown two here as an example.

The question is I need to extract all nodes  that has classification attribute value of "paymenttype" and attribute value of category as "Wallet". Then extract the 'title' from the results and store as dictionary or List. Once extracted store this is a list or Dictionary for Comparison between the extracted nodes.

```
<PatientDetailsXML>             
 <PList> 
               <PName type="Patient">
            <properties>
                <Room bedType="Auto" />
                <PName title="Joe Beom" PId="1234">
                    <Details>
                        <classification classification="paymenttype" category="Wallet" />
                        <classification classification="Humor" category="None" />
                        <classification classification="Food" category="Fruit" />
                    </Details>
                </PName>
                </properties>
            <childEvents>
            </childEvents>
        </PName>
                <PName type="Patient">
            <properties>
                <Room bedType="Auto" />
                <PName title="John Bair" PId="5678">
                    <Details>
                        <classification classification="paymenttype" category="Found" />
                        <classification classification="Humor" category="None" />
                        <classification classification="Food" category="Fruit" />
                    </Details>
                </PName>
                </properties>
            <childEvents>
            </childEvents>
        </PName>
</PList>
</PatientDetailsXML>
```

I have attempted as below but can't seem to get it right:

```
 XElement root = XElement.Load("patientdetails.xml");
       IEnumerable<XElement> tests =

          from el in root.Elements("PName")
          where ((string)el.Element("properties").Element("PName").Element("Details").Element("classification").Attribute("paymenttype") == "EventType") && (string)el.Element("properties").Element("PName").Element("Details").Element("classification").Attribute("category") == "Wallet")

          select el;  



       foreach (XElement el in tests)
        {

         Console.WriteLine (el);
          }
```

**EDIT (My Second Attempt):**

```
XmlTextReader Readers = new XmlTextReader("patientdetails.xml");
       XmlDocument docs = new XmlDocument();
       docs.Load(Readers);


   foreach (XmlNode n in docs.SelectNodes(@"//PName/properties/PName/Details/classification[@classification='paymenttype' and @category='Wallet']"))
   {
                Console.WriteLine(n.ParentNode.ParentNode.OuterXml);
   }
```

Comment: Please check my second attempt I got it working but is this the right way to do it, is there a better way. And now how can I store in list or Dictionary for doing compare between the extraction.

Comment: The second attemps should work but you use 'Pname' instead of 'PName' and Xml/Xpath is case sensitive.

Comment: You can use XML serialization/de-serialization to achieve this. With de-serialization you will get complete XML in list or dictionary format. On which you can apply Linq query to get node matching to your criteria. This is very simple instead of working XPATHs.  See this link https://blog.udemy.com/csharp-serialize-to-xml/

Comment: Instead of checking why not you use `//classification[@classification='paymenttype' and @category='Wallet']` if you need only `classification` node() if XML structure is same.

Comment: @SimonMourier: that's a typo please ignore that I will correct it but I tested it works. Now i'm have an issue from the extraction that I did how do I extract the 'title' in the foreach loop.

Comment: @AmrendraKumar: I'm looking to extract the `title` that's why need the whole node. The second attempt sees to be working but i'm just scratching my head how to extract the title from the extraction in the foreach loop

Comment: Update your question with all what you need instead of adding requirements in the comments

Comment: @SimonMourier: done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I corrected your first attempt (LINQ). It returns first `<PName type="Patient">` from xml in question.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> tests =
    from el in root.Element("PList").Elements("PName")
    let c = el.Descendants("classification")
    where c.Where(x => x.Attribute("classification").Value == "paymenttype"
                    && x.Attribute("category").Value == "Wallet").Any()
    select el;
```

Then you can iterate `tests` and extract what you want.

```
foreach (var el in tests)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        el.Element("properties")
          .Element("PName")
          .Attribute("title")
          .Value);
}
```

---

I also corrected your second attempt (XPath). It will return title value of `<PName title="Joe Beom" PId="1234">`.

```
var query = @"//PName[Details/classification[@classification='paymenttype' and @category='Wallet']]/@title";
foreach (XmlNode n in docs.SelectNodes(query))
{
    Console.WriteLine(n.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, this will select the right node, then how do I extract the title from this

Comment: I've updated answer. Also if you need only titles you can select it in LINQ expression.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that. It's working as I need it. Just have a quick question will the xelement as you are using in your answer be quick or xpath as I used in the second attempt be quick in terms of speed of fetching data.

Comment: I think xpath would be faster, but I can't confirm it.

Comment: Your Xpath isn't working as there is no `title` under `classification`. `title` is under 'properties/PName'

Comment: It works for me. In xpath in my answer `@title` is under `PName`.

Comment: Apologies, it's working. I did a type in the query while testing it. Thanks I'm accepting this as an answer

Comment: one more thing if I need to get the type also in the  `<PName type="Patient">` , can I simply do it like this: `var query = @"//PName[Details/classification[@classification='paymenttype' and @category='Wallet']]/@title/@type";`, or do I need to do another foreach for the type

Comment: It's not that simple. It's better to return outer `<PName>` and get what you need with C# code. So maybe just use LINQ - it would be cleaner.

Comment: Yes, I got this working. BUt now I have a issue with Bedtype, If you can kindly please help me with this. Does it look like I can fetch the bedtype and title from one query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185613/discussion-between-mike-kaskun-and-user726720).